# ColdFusion Exception help: coldfusion.runtime.NoOperScope cannot be cast to coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationScope

Tags: sql-server-2005, coldfusion, cfc

I am encountering an exception cause by the CFINVOKEARGUMENT line of the following snippet:

```
<CFOUTPUT query="cfmx.Messages"><CFSILENT>
<CFINVOKE component="com_VUI_RemoveIllegalChars" method="formatString" returnvariable="cfmx.formattedMessage">
   <CFINVOKEARGUMENT name="inString" value="#TTSText#">
</CFINVOKE>
</CFSILENT>
```

The exact text of the exception is:

> Error casting an object of type
>   coldfusion.runtime.NoOperScope cannot
>   be cast to
>   coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationScope to
>   an incompatible type. This usually
>   indicates a programming error in Java,
>   although it could also mean you have
>   tried to use a foreign object in a
>   different way than it was designed.
>   coldfusion.runtime.NoOperScope cannot
>   be cast to
>   coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationScope

Notes:

- cfmx.Messages is an object returned in a CFPROCRESULT, and upon examination via CFDUMP it does contain the expected data
- com_VUI_RemoveIllegalChars has not changed at all
- TTSText is a valid column in the result set
- My suspicion is that this may be a ColdFusion configuration issue

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed any light on what may be causing this problem.

EDIT: Complete dump from the exception log:

> "Error","jrpp-11","01/06/09","15:11:37",,"coldfusion.runtime.NoOperScope
>   cannot be cast to
>   coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationScope
>   The specific sequence of files
>   included or processed is:
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ermsvui\proc_playsitestatus.cfm,
>   line: 30 "
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   coldfusion.runtime.NoOperScope cannot
>   be cast to
>   coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationScope
>     at
>   coldfusion.runtime.RuntimeServiceImpl.getFullTagName(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:625)
>     at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getFullName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1082)
>     at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:184)
>     at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:157)
>     at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1267)
>     at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1218)
>     at
>   coldfusion.tagext.lang.InvokeTag.doEndTag(InvokeTag.java:358)
>     at
>   cfproc_playsitestatus2ecfm1824676963.runPage(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ermsvui\proc_playsitestatus.cfm:30)
>     at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:192)
>     at
>   coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:366)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:279)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:27)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>     at
>   coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:175)
>     at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
>     at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>     at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:284)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

The above code snippet contains lines 28 - 32 of proc_playsitestatus.cfm

EDIT:

The value of TTS text is this case is "The message for test is"

The source of com_VUI_RemoveIllegalChars:

```
<CFCOMPONENT displayname="Format a string for use in VoiceXML" hint="returns a string formatted for voiceXML" output="yes">
    <CFFUNCTION name="formatString" access="public" returntype="string" displayname="Format String" hint="Formats String for VoiceXML">
        <cfargument name="inString" type="string" required="true" displayname="input string" hint="pass in the string to be formatted">
        <CFSET v.messageWithoutChars = replace(inString, "<", "", "all")>
        <CFSET v.messageWithoutChars = replace(v.messageWithoutChars, ">", "", "all")>
        <CFSET v.messageWithoutChars = replace(v.messageWithoutChars, "&", "and", "all")>
        <CFSET v.messageWithoutChars = REReplace(v.messageWithoutChars, "\.+", ".", "all")>
        <CFSET v.messageWithoutChars = replace(v.messageWithoutChars, "!", ".", "all")>
        <CFSET v.messageWithoutChars = replace(v.messageWithoutChars, "\", " ", "all")>
        <CFSET v.messageWithoutChars = replace(v.messageWithoutChars, "/", " ", "all")>
        <CFSET v.messageWithoutChars = REReplace(v.messageWithoutChars, "[[:punct:]]{2,}", " ", "all")>
        <cfreturn v.messageWithoutChars>
    </CFFUNCTION>
</CFCOMPONENT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting "Enable Application Variables" was not enabled in the ColdFusion configuration.

Comment: Interesting, considering your code never mentions the Application scope. Is that used elsewhere that isn't included in your code samples? If not, I'm really curious why this setting would matter.

Comment: I've posted all relevant code here, the rest is just cruft dealing with VXML output. This one had my colleague and I scratching our heads as well. I'm going to investigate this further and I will post my results once I have some.

Comment: Ah yes, that would make sense.  The clue is the error message: "coldfusion.runtime.NoOperScope cannot be cast to coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationScope", indicating that you're trying to use the Application scope.  Inside a <CFOUTPUT> or <CFLOOP>, the scope resolution rules change, so that may be a clue.  Also, what is the "v" scope in your component?  It's possible that the reason the error is getting thrown on the <CFINVOKE> is because it's invoking an implicit constructor on the component (whatever initializes the "v" variable) before invoking the desired method.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about that line #? I'm thinking the error is in the CFC method itself. Can you check that, and if I'm right, post the line from the CFC method?

Comment: I won't rule out it being a problem with the CFC, however the exception log (as posted in my most recent edit) is complaining about code in proc_playsitestatus.cfm of which I've posted lines 28 - 32.

Answer (score 0):

Without the contents of the `com_VUI_RemoveIllegalChars` component and the value of the `TTSText` variable, you're not giving us a lot to go on, here. Could you post those? (I understand that sometimes you can't for NDA/etc reasons)